Where Can I find PIC32 Library Functions Contents?
I am searching for PIC32 Library Functions' context. For example there is a uart.h library and "void UARTEnable( UART_MODULE id, UART_ENABLE_MODE mode );" in it. When I used that function UARTx is enabling but I don't know what is happening in the background. Which pins are being enabled or disabled, which registers are being driven. Where is uart.c for uart.h to describe UARTEnable function context.
I have searched for a file like uart.c for uart.h or functions descriptions in MPLAP IDE but I can't find.

Look for the Mikrochip mcc.

Still not found please help?

I have found the answer, thank all of you people who interested in my question. I have only .h files in XC32 compiler path. I have look to the Microchip PLIB Library page, and download .exe file to install library files. That .exe file create a file ...\pic32-libs and that path consists of source files of library files that I mentioned in first question.

The PLIB is pretty old. Microchip recommends using MPLAB Harmony for new projects.

If you want to use the library functions for the PIC32 you had to install MPLAB Harmony framework.
https://www.microchip.com/en-us/tools-resources/configure/mplab-harmony
If you want to work with an 8 or 16 bit controller use the MPLAB MCC:
https://www.microchip.com/en-us/tools-resources/configure/mplab-code-configurator
